# Unable to install yum and mysql,ssh

Tags: ssh, yum, mysql

When I go to install mysql on CentOS 6,I get the following error:

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

I think I do not have `Yum` installed. Please let me know the corresponding steps.

I am also unable to install `SSH` on Ubuntu.

Comment: If you run `cd /tmp; wget http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os`, what is the output?

Comment: The `403` error means that you are forbidden access to the server.  You could navigate to the URL with your browser to see what you get.  Also, are you running behind a proxy server?  Try running `yum clean all` followed by `yum upgrade`.

Comment: BTW, `yum` is definitely installed. You would have a `file not found` error or similar if it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly telling that 403 error that means it maybe a network fault of you that your centos server is not getting Internet Connection or CentOS Repos are down.